# Insert ID manually for JPA in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

How can I insert id manually for this JPA entity in Spring boot? I don't want the id to be autogenerated. I tried sending a POST request using postman sending this JSON object to a RestController:

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "name":"New York"
}
```

I get an error saying that I should manually assing id. Why it is not taking the id that I'm passing in the request?

The Code:

Entity

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class City{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 
}
```

Controller:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class CityService{
    private CityService cityService;

    @Autowired
    public void setCityService(CityService CityService) {
        this.CityService = CityService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/cities")
     public void cities(@RequestBody City city){
         cityService.save(city);
     }

}
```

Service:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CityService {

    private CityRepository cityRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CityServiceImpl(CityRepository cityRepository) {
        this.cityRepository= cityRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveCity(City city) {
        CityRepository.save(city);
    }

}
```

Comment: If an entity has a primary key field that is not marked with @GeneratedValue, automatic primary key value is not generated and the application is responsible to set a primary key by initializing the primary key field. That must be done before any attempt to persist the entity object

Comment: Try to print the object City before you call the cityRepository.save();

Comment: Did you debug your code. Does the id field has a value before save. It seems that in json you pass id as String, may be value not set into city. Try to pass number without ", like "id":1

Comment: Id has no value after save().

Comment: Can I see your `City` class?

Answer (score 0):

Theres probably something wrong with your setters. Try generating them again.

Answer (score 0):

There was an old table with a different structure in the database. There was no error in the code.